# Auto-complete only filenames with bash when running vim?

Tags: bash, vim

Is there some plugin for bash that will modify tab complete when I'm trying to open a file with vim? For example, if I have a directory with the following files:

- foo/
- foo.c
- foo
- bar.c
- bar/

(where foo/ and bar/ are directories, and foo is a binary file)

and I do this:

> vim f

and then hit tab, is there a way for the autocomplete to ignore the foo/ and foo binary files, and automatically fill it in with "foo.c", since that's the only text file that starts with f?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! It's not really a *plugin* per se, but you can edit bash's autocomplete configuration file to match parameters for specific applications. On Debian-based systems, you'll find this configuration file at `/etc/bash_completion`.

In fact, there's a handy [guide to modifying `/etc/bash_completion`](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/316) over at Debian Administration. I'm sure you could modify filename completion to only accept non-binary files.